# How to jump to specific sections of a sprite sheet in css?

Tags: html, css, animation, sprite

I have a video that I took frames out of and then built a sprite sheet with them. I'm trying to animate back this sprite sheet in a website using CSS. My problem is that the animation is ''rolling'' through the sprite sheet instead of jumping to specific sections. What I mean by this is that you could see half of one frame with another half of the next frame if the frame rate is too slow. This is weird to me since I followed the guide here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps

How do I make the animation jump to specific sections of the sprite sheet instead of just ''rolling''?

This is the code that I used:

```
#video{
  width: 426px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url("spritesheet/sheetTest.png") left center;
  animation: play 33s steps(33) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -27328px; }
}
```

one frame is 426x240 and the width of the entire sheet is 27328.

Comment: with 33 frames of 426px, how can your sprite be 27328px? I would expect it to be 14058px...

Comment: yeah just realized this as well.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I didn't have the good amount of frames... If this is happening to you to; check your number of frames/steps!